# ORA-01722: invalid number

Tags: sql, oracle

Добрый день всем. Совсем не вижу, где я число некорректно написал... Помогите найти ошибку в sql скрипте, пожалуйста.
P.S.: ошибку выдает без указания неправильной строки или еще чего. Если кто то спросит.

```
select distinct  
  'childal', 
  child.id, 
  child.municid,
  dateend,
  (select ADOPTACCESSPACKAGE.getrealchildfio(child.id, child.municid, 1)from dual) as ФИО, 
  (select ADOPTACCESSPACKAGE.GETREALCHILDBIRTHDAY(child.id, child.municid, 1)from dual) as Дата_рождения,
  coalesce(
    (select t.ustr
     from (select q.ustr, q.datebegin, q.childid, q.municid 
           from (select childid, municid, 'Опека' as ustr, dateend, datebegin 
                 from guardian 
                 where datebegin is not null and (dateend is null or dateend is not null and to_date(dateend,'dd.mm.yyyy')>sysdate)
                 union select childid, municid, 'Предварительная опека' as ustr, dateend, datebegin 
                       from prevguardian 
                       where datebegin is not null and (dateend is null or dateend is not null and to_date(dateend,'dd.mm.yyyy')>sysdate)
                       union select childid, municid, 'Приёмная семья' as ustr, dateend, datebegin 
                             from foster 
                             where datebegin is not null and (dateend is null or dateend is not null and to_date(dateend,'dd.mm.yyyy')>sysdate)
                             union select childid, municid, 'Усыновление' as ustr, dateend, datebegin
                                   from adopt 
                                   where datebegin is not null and (dateend is null or dateend is not null and to_date(dateend,'dd.mm.yyyy')>sysdate)
                                   union select childid, municid, 'Патронат' as ustr, dateend, datebegin 
                                         from patronat 
                                         where datebegin is not null and (dateend is null or dateend is not null and to_date(dateend,'dd.mm.yyyy')>sysdate)
                                         union select childid, municid, 'Учреждения для детей-сирот и детей оставшихся б/п' as ustr, dateend, datebegin 
                                               from internat 
                                               where datebegin is not null  and (dateend is null or dateend is not null and to_date(dateend,'dd.mm.yyyy')>sysdate)
                                               union select childid, municid, 'Учреждения временного содержания' as ustr, dateend, datebegin      
                                                     from temporaryhouse 
                                                     where datebegin is not null and (dateend is null or dateend is not null and to_date(dateend,'dd.mm.yyyy')>sysdate) 
                                                     union select childid, municid, 'Патронаж' as ustr, dateend, datebegin
                                                           from patronag 
                                                           where datebegin is not null and (dateend is null or dateend is not null and to_date(dateend,'dd.mm.yyyy')>sysdate) 
                )q
           order by to_date(q.datebegin,'dd.mm.yyyy')desc
          )t
     inner join child
     on t.childid = child.id
     where rownum <= 1 and t.municid = child.municid),
    'Нет действующего устройства'
  ) as Устройство,
  (select UTILSFUNCTIONPACKAGE.getnameregion(child.municid, 0)from dual) As Район  
from child  
inner join (
  (
    select childid, municid, dateend 
    from (select mu.childid, mu.municid, mu.datebegin, mu.dateend 
          from (select childid, municid, datebegin, dateend 
                from guardian 
                where datebegin is not null 
                union select childid, municid, datebegin, dateend 
                      from prevguardian where datebegin is not null 
                      union select childid, municid, datebegin, dateend 
                            from foster 
                            where datebegin is not null 
                            union select childid, municid, datebegin, dateend 
                                  from adopt 
                                  where datebegin is not null
                                  union select childid, municid, datebegin, dateend 
                                        from patronat 
                                        where datebegin is not null 
                                        union select childid, municid, datebegin, dateend 
                                              from internat
                                              where datebegin is not null 
                                              union select childid, municid, datebegin, dateend 
                                                    from temporaryhouse 
                                                    where datebegin is not null 
                                                    union select childid, municid, datebegin, dateend 
                                                          from patronag 
                                                          where datebegin is not null
          ) mu, child 
          where child.municid = mu.childid and 
              mu.municid = child.municid and 
              mu.datebegin is not null and 
              to_date(mu.datebegin, 'dd.mm.yyyy') = to_date('02.08.2017','dd.mm.yyyy')
        )
  )
)z 
on z.childid = child.id and 
   z.municid = child.municid  
inner join people 
on people.id = child.peopleid and 
   people.municid = child.municid  
where child.param <> 1 and 
      child.municid in ('{BA986261-AC49-4F7B-AC0D-8B4A6AFD9364}', '{FE00E848-55B3-4E7F-8E15-8DB24F132A45}') 
order by 5 asc;
```

Comment: У вас есть много сравнений дат. Возможно там где то в поле лежит не дата и не получается сделать `to_date`. То есть с точки зрения синтаксиса запрос скорее всего написан правильно и ошибка выскакивает при его выполнении.

Comment: 1. Как минимум, в конце первого `inner join` в этом месте - `) )
)z` не хватает еще одно алиаса для таблицы. 2. Попробуйте комментить куски кода, чтобы самому локализовать ошибку. На вскидку сложно сказать, где ошибка.

Comment: @Denis В оракле алиасы для выборок не обязательны, если к ним нет обращений.

Comment: @Mike перешел на MySQL с Oracle, подзабыл уже)

Comment: А так ошибка может быть где угодно. даже например в `child.param <> 1` если после param в БД символьное и в какой от записи попавшей под выборку в этом поле лежит не число. не видя структуры ваших таблц и данных что то конкретное посоветовать невозможно

Comment: @IDrakonl, если я выполняю выборку, там где даты, ошибок не выдает, так что это точно не здесь проблема.
В child - PARAM NUMBER(38,0). То есть и здесь вроде не должно быть проблем.

Comment: Разбейте ваш запрос на части и выполняйте их. Метод половинного деления всегда помогает в подобных ситуациях

Comment: Ваша ошибка может возникнуть в любом месте, где происходит явное или не явное преобразование типов. Фактически в любом месте, где вы написали <колонка> условие <колонка>. Как уже говорил Mike, глядя на ваш запрос не возможно идентифицировать ошибку не видя структур таблиц..

Comment: @IDrakonl, идея известная, как раз этим и занимаюсь. Пока ни к чему не пришел и решил здесь написать. По поводу структуры  таблиц, у них очень много полей, и не знаю даже как ее тут разместить, если до конца рабочего дня не найду решение проблемы без этого, то все таки обновлю вопрос. Разбираю а. конюшни после предыдущего разработчика...

Comment: @VladislavKuznetsov Все таки для начала посмотрите какой тип данных у колонки param в БД. потому что это единственное место где я вижу прямую возможность неявного преобразования типов

Comment: @Mike, я нашел ошибку в этом месте - child.municid in ('{BA986261-AC49-4F7B-AC0D-8B4A6AFD9364}', '{FE00E848-55B3-4E7F-8E15-8DB24F132A45}') . Суть в том, что здесь уже в пустой выборке применяются условия эти. Может как то вызвать ту ошибку такая ситуация? Выборка к моменту принятия условий пуста. А та колонка MUNICID VARCHAR2(38 CHAR).

Comment: ну это что то невероятное. тут же в IN просто два char сравнивается с varchar, конвертации в число в принципе быть не может

Comment: @Mike, проверил на другом похоже запросе, там в этом же самом месте, которые я чуть вышел упомянул в комментарии, нет никаких ошибок, если выборка пустая. И согласен, что это странно все немного.

Comment: @VladislavKuznetsov Ваши айди выглядят как guid с оформлением для читаемости. Похоже они где-то не явно конвертируются обратно в raw(16). У вас точно нигде не используется raw? Поробуйте убрать красоту, т.е. скобки и дефисы, и повторить запрос. Ошибка повторится?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я нашел проблему в своем sql запросе.

```
child.municid = mu.childid
   VARCHAR2  vs  NUMBER
```

Разные типы здесь. Всем большое спасибо, кто писал мне в комментариях!

Comment: Дополните ответ, какие типа имеют упомянутые колонки?

Comment: @0xdb, Дополнил.